# Failed to start Microsoft Hyper-V VM with RemoteFX VGPU using Windows 10 Pro and a Radeon RX 480

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, virtual-machine, hyper-v, remotefx

I have a computer running Windows 10 Pro, completely up to date, equipped with an AMD FX 8350 CPU and a Radeon RX 480 graphics card. I followed [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-remotefx-vgpu#configure-the-remotefx-vgpu-3d-adapter) to set up Microsoft Hyper-V with RemoteFX VGPU and create a VM with this technology enabled. According to [this guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2505694/error-message-when-you-try-to-start-a-remotefx-enabled-virtual-machine), my GPU more than amply passes the minimum requirements for using RemoteFX: being discrete, supporting DirectX 9c and 10 (it supports DirectX 12), and having enough free VRAM to assign to my host (I regularly run games that use much more than the 128 MB VRAM I'm assigning to my VM).

However, when I try to start the VM, I get the following error:

> Synthetic 3D Display Controller (Instance ID XXXXXXX): Failed to Power On with Error 'Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.'. The virtual machine cannot be started because a worker session cannot be created.

I tried to see if I could install [the RemoteFX cap driver](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817577(v=ws.10).aspx), but it doesn't seems to be available for Windows 10, probably only for Windows Server (dism exits with an error message saying the RemoteFX cap driver package does not exist or something). I already checked that [my group policy for message text for users trying to log on is disabled](https://support.microsoft.com/es-mx/help/2506391/in-windows-server-2008-r2-service-pack-1--remotefx-virtual-machines-ca). Having already checked these possible causes, I haven't been able to find online anything else I could try.

Comment: What OS is installed in the guest VM?

Comment: I haven't installed a guest OS yet. I can't even start the VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft article
[Set up and configure RemoteFX vGPU for Remote Desktop Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-remotefx-vgpu) that you cited details the requirements and
installation procedure.

One of the requirements is :

> - Guest VM running a **Windows Enterprise client** (Windows 7 with Service Pack 1, Windows 8.1, Windows 10) or **Windows Server** (Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows Server 2016).

I expect that you will need to upgrade your Windows 10 Professional host and VM
to Enterprise in order to have a chance of making this work
(or at least of proceeding up to the next problem).

The Wikipedia article for
[RemoteFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RemoteFX)
also lists the supported platforms as :
Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2016,
Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: So that means I'm going to have to acquire Windows 10 Enterprise or set up Windows Server on another computer. That's a bummer... but it's better than not knowing what to do. Have 50 reputation for that.